# Big-O complexity of calculation: Drawing a non-colliding subset of k elements from n total with dumb algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, probability

I'm trying to understand the computational complexity of this pseudocode:

```
values is a set of n unique elements
subset is an empty set
for 0 ... k
    X: randomly select a value from values
       if value is in subset
           goto X
       else
           insert value into subset
```

This is of course a (poor) algorithm for selecting a unique random subset of k elements from n, and I'm aware of the better choices, but I wanted to understand the computational complexity of this.

I can see easily that this is O(n) when duplicates are allowed because the conditional test is eliminated from the pseudocode and k choices are made each time.

When you have to account for duplicates, there is a probability that a re-test will be required which increases with each iteration. Depending on the values of n and k, this is a non-negligible fact, but I'm not certain how it affects the big-O complexity in a generalized way. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: This question is probably better of on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). But are you asking it's effect  vs an algorithm that removes the data from the set when it puts it in the subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of inserting value into subset for each value of k is (n-k)/n

The number of iterations of each k loop would be inversely proportional to that probability

Therefore Big O notation for each value of k would be O((n/(n-K)) + 1) where 1 would be 'insert value into subset'.

You have to calculate the summation of ((n/(n-K)) + 1) for each value of k ----final answer would be 
O(((n/(n-K)) + 1) for k from 1 through k)

Disclaimer - this is assuming if Big(o) is applicable for functions that use random number generating algorithms (since X is random)